# Linux: Redshift is blinking

Tags: arch-linux, x11, redshift, composite, picom

I am using Arch linux with i3wm and picom as compositor. I would like to be able to use `redshift`. But when I launch `redshift`, it turns itself on and off every two seconds, resulting in annoying screen blinking.

What can I do to stop this blinking and use `redshift` in peace?

Comment: Could be having trouble with your location. Go here - http://jonls.dk/redshift/ - and look at the sample config file.

Comment: Maybe two instances of redshift running, that also leads to annoying blinking as they fight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to manually set my longitude and latitude in `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf`:

```
[manual]
lat=MYLAST
lon=MYLON
```

another thing to pay attention to is making sure you are running only one instance of redshift.

---

Thanks to @ajgringo619 and @Simon Richter for their suggestions